# Imaplib syntax error in Terminal but not in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, imaplib

I'm starting out learning Python 3 on Linux and am attempting to write a script to notify me when I receive emails from certain people. The following code works fine in IDLE3 but I am encountering an invalid syntax error when I try to run it from Terminal:

```
    tcd = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
    tcd.login(addr, password)
    tcd.select('INBOX', readonly=False)
```

The Terminal error is as follows:

```
    File "mailcheck.py", line 22
      tcd = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the line before this. Rookie mistakes >:-/